# Center vector of CIFilter

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image, cifilter

I'm having a hard time understanding the meaning of the center vector used by many different CIFilters.

Let's take `CIRadialGradient` for example, what does the `inputCenter` mean? What's its values range? How does its coordinate system behave etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian said, it's just a type that encodes a position where the effect is centered. HOWEVER, CoreImage coordinates are inverted on the Y-axis from what you're used to using on iOS: The 0,0 point is the lower-left corner and the y value increases as you move toward the top of the screen.

Comment: So what's the meaning of it in CIPixellate filter?

Comment: It adjusts the offset of the pixel grid from the source image, which can have a major effect on the outcome, particularly for large pixel sizes.

Comment: Can you please further explain the effect in CIPixellate filter? "offset of the pixel grid from the source image" - what does it mean?

Comment: It changes the sample point for each pixel in the grid, which results in a somewhat different output.

Answer (score 0):

The inputCenter for that CIFilter is the center of the two concentric circles. So it is a point in your view/image. The default value is  [150 150], so I imagine that acceptable values can be any values in the view plane (positive or negative).

Some rudimentary info is here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIRadialGradient

Comment: So what's the meaning of it in CIPixellate filter?

Comment: Thats a good question! It seems like it is unnecessary for CIPixellate, at least to me, since the pixilation is more like a general matrix filter and just processes the entire image plane.

Comment: The pixel mosaic doesn't need to line up perfectly with the boundaries of the source image (which happens when the height and width are not both a multiple of the pixel size).

Comment: @BrianTrzupek it definitely affects the placement of the pixelations, how is unclear and undocumented though.