# How can I fix a Core Image's CILanczosScaleTransform filter border artifact?

Tags: ios, image-processing, core-graphics, core-image, lanczos

I want to implement an image downscaling algorithm for iOS. After reading that Core Images's `CILanczosScaleTransform` was a great fit for it, I implemented it the following way:

```
public func resizeImage(_ image: UIImage, targetWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    assert(targetWidth > 0.0)

    let scale = Double(targetWidth) / Double(image.size.width)

    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else {
        fatalError("Couldn't create CIImage from image in input")
    }

    guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CILanczosScaleTransform") else {
        fatalError("The filter CILanczosScaleTransform is unavailable on this device.")
    }

    filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(scale, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)

    guard let result = filter.outputImage else {
        fatalError("No output on filter.")
    }

    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result, from: result.extent) else {
        fatalError("Couldn't create CG Image")
    }

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}
```

It works well but I get a classic border artifact probably due to the pixel-neighborhood base of the algorithm. I couldn't find anything in Apple's doc about this. **Is there something smarter than rendering a bigger image and then crop the border to solve this issue?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `imageByClampingToExtent`.

> Calling this method ... creates an image of infinite extent by repeating
>   pixel colors from the edges of the original image.

You could use it like this:

```
...
guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)?.clampedToExtent() else {
    fatalError("Couldn't create CIImage from image in input")
}
```

See more information here: [Apple Doc for clampedtoextent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1437628-clampedtoextent)

Comment: That + some CGRect sizing done right (ie `floor`calls) = ✌️ — Thanks @Stephan