# Running a CIFilter on an image creates an undesired offset above and below

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, core-image, cifilter

I'm facing an issue while using `CIFilter` where it applies an offset/border above and below the image it outputs. It can be seen in the example below.

[image]

In this example I am simply taking a UIImage, applying `CIPixellate`, fixing the orientation and then displaying this image in a fullscreen `UIImageView` with a background colour of red to demonstrate the issue (setting the background colour to the default colour 'clear' produces a white offset. Below are the settings for the `UIImageView`.

[image: UIImageView settings]

By debugging I know that the issue occurs somewhere while the `CIFilter` is applied and it is not related to the UIImageView, if I simply pass the image without the filter then this issue does not occur.

For reference, here is the code I am using to pixelate the image:

```
extension UIImage {
    func pixellate(amount: Int) -> UIImage? {
        let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: self.cgImage!)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate")
        filter?.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter?.setValue(amount, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)
        guard let outputImage = filter?.outputImage else { return nil }

        var pixellatedImage: UIImage?

// Fix the orientation of the newly processed image
        let context = CIContext()
        if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
            let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)

            let portraitImage = UIImage(cgImage: processedImage.cgImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
            pixellatedImage = portraitImage
        }

        return pixellatedImage
    }
}
```

What is happening here? Is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many image filters must include neighbour pixels into the calculation of a target pixel. Of course, this causes problems at the edges. One possibility is to repeat pixels at the edges. Apple offers a convenient way to do this: 
**clampedToExtent**

> Calling this method ... creates an image of infinite extent by
>   repeating pixel colors from the edges of the original image.

```
...
let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: self.cgImage!).clampedToExtent()
```

See also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49309714/2331445

Comment: This was exactly the issue, thanks so much for the solution.

Comment: also note that you can run a "croppedTo" at the end with the original image extents.